# python, converting to binary vector from integer

Tags: python

how can I make from:

```
a1=2
a2=3
b1=1
b2=4
```

a binary vector like this:

```
     0,1,2,3,4
a = [0,0,1,1,0]
b = [0,1,0,0,1]
```

I mean that integers here define me the indexes in vectors, where it should be '1'. How is the fastest way to do this?

Comment: The fastest way would be to type `[0, 0, 1, 1, 0 ]` if you're typing out all those variables.... however, I'm guessing they're probably coming from a different source or in a different format? I'd suggest reading and making sure you're not falling into the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 2):

How about simply using `a1` and `a2` as indices like so:

```
a = [0] * 5
a[a1] = 1
a[a2] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For your example, it would be

```
a = [0] * 5
b = [0] * 5
a1 = 2
a2 = 3
b1 = 1
b2 = 4

a[a1] = 1
a[a2] = 1
b[b1] = 1
b[b2] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. This way it could work for every amount of indexes without hardcoding anything more than needed.

```
oneIndexesA = [a1,a2]
oneIndexesB = [b1,b2]

a = [0] * (max(oneIndexesA) + 1)
for x in oneIndexesA:  
    a[x] = 1

b = [0] * (max(oneIndexesB) + 1)
for x in oneIndexesB:  
    b[x] = 1
```